# Is there any regexp replacement?

Tags: javascript, regex, dsl

Yesterday I've been lost, when I tried to produce a regexp with regexp, I've failed to escape out the escaped escapes (for JavaScript). Regexps are great for CLI Unix pipe chains and in once-used-shell-scripts, or when I want a quick-and-dirty solution for something, but I don't want to maintain a program, which uses regexps. Regexps are unreadable, hard to debug etc., etc.

Are there any other line-oriented string manipulation package/language/whatsoever beyond regexp? Or a good language which produces regexp?

Comment: depends on what you're using them for. there's lots of tools that USE regular expression matching (`sed/awk`, `grep`, etc), but as far as "pattern matching in strings" goes, a regex is basically your only option, i.e. you'll need to learn regex syntax. that said, some languages (e.g. perl) support comments in regexes, which help explain them. also, sometimes a different tool is better for the job you need to do (such as using an xml parser to parse html), or passing data as JSON instead

Comment: Commenting regexp is not enough for me. I want to use a search/replace tool, which is readable without comments and also easy to learn.

Comment: i'm not sure i get it. what do you need to do that regexes won't work for?

Comment: I have no problems with features or speed of regexp. It's ugly: hard to understand, impossible to debug. It's a quick-and-dirty thing, not a professional tool. Just take a look on the SQL. Even a non-tech guy can understand it: "select release,title from films where release > 2001 order by title". Now, try it with regexp.

Comment: well, some things are complicated and require some knowledge to understand - there's a reason tech guys make so much, after all. :) i'm not sure how you'd go about creating an easier to use tool for pattern matching in strings than regex. instead, you might try using the posix character classes (e.g. `[:digit:]`) instead of perl-style (e.g. `\d`), but imo that's just more typing for no reason

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned regexes are actually quite high-level already. They're obtuse for sure and the learning curve is steep, but it's short: you can read everything you need to know about a regex flavor on one HTML page, which certainly isn't true for e.g. Python.

So if you have a regex but it's making you feel like your brain is leaking out your ears and you'd be a lot happier if it was just more explicit, I'd go *down* a level, not up. Writing some kind of state machine instead of just using pattern matching may even clarify your logic.

Answer (score 2):

A nice stuff appeared on my Twitter stream: [VerbalExpressions](https://github.com/jehna/VerbalExpressions).

Quote from the documentation:

```
var tester = VerEx()
            .startOfLine()
            .then( "http" )
            .maybe( "s" )
            .then( "://" )
            .maybe( "www." )
            .anythingBut( " " )
            .endOfLine();
```

That's I talk about: readable, maintenable code, instead of fuzzy series of special characters.